# Why symbolic links have no data blocks allocated to them in ext4fs?

Tags: files, filesystems, symlink, ext4, inode

I am a Unix wanderer. I just noticed that symlinks don't have data blocks allocated to them, I think the inode of the symlink file stores the filename which the symlink refers to, is this actually the case?

```
$ stat sdb
  File: sdb -> /dev/sdb
  Size: 8               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: 803h/2051d      Inode: 26348139    Links: 1
....
```

I could only imagine one possibility for now, the inode of sdb symlink contains among other things (i,e. owner, permissions...) + `/dev/sdb` path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ext4 [stores the target of a symbolic link inside the inode](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Symbolic_Links), if the target is less than 60 bytes long. Longer targets will be stored in a data block.